# Visual Studio 2019 Could not add the account - An error occurred while sending the request

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-2019, team-project

I've finished to set up my Visual Studio 2019 and when I tried to connect to team project the following message appears.

---

### Microsoft Visual Studio

We could not add the account

### An error occurred while sending the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above response is valid, so I have to post what the Issue was.

I was setting up my windows 10 and I put the Chrome browser as default, I reversed those changes to explorer and then I could add my account to manage the team projects without any issue.

Comment: Why on earth is this even a problem?

Comment: I don't know, ask to Microsoft. @ThanasisIoannidis

Comment: I had similar problem. But resetting default browser didn't solve it

Comment: changing browser doesn't solve problem

Answer (score 1):

An error occurred while sending the request, looks like there is some issue with the network.

You need to check if you can login to your tfs project from your local browser.

You call follow the steps [connecting visual studio 2019 to TFS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/connect-to-projects?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio-2019#connect-from-visual-studio-or-team-explorer), Select the **Manage Connections** button in **Team Explorer** to open the **Connect page**. Choose **Connect to a Project** then click **Add Azure DevOps Server** and enter URL to your tfs server.

Then follow the detailed steps to [Configure Visual Studio to connect to Azure DevOps Proxy Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/projects/connect-to-projects?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio-2019#configure-visual-studio-to-connect-to-azure-devops-proxy-server).